# Click Button from Generic.xaml?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I am writing a custom control in Silverlight and I am having issues getting my Button to click to the Generic.xaml file. This does not work:

```
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ScrollableTabControl">
                    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ScrollLeft" Click="scrollLeft">&lt;</Button>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
```

"ScrollLeft" is in my C# file.

However this does not work either:

```
        var b = this.GetTemplateChild("ScrollLeft");
        Debug.Assert(b != null);
```

Because no matter what I do, b always comes back null. I feel like there should be an easy way to assign the click method to this button, so what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: This is the method from my C# file:

```
    public void scrollLeft(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //var scroller = Application.Current.Resources["TabScroller"] as ScrollViewer;
        //scroller.LineLeft();
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code (including method name) for the click event handler?

Comment: I've edited it so it has that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the **OnApplyTemplate()** on your custom control class (C# File).

Like this.

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        Button btn = GetTemplateChild("ScrollLeft") as Button;
        Debug.Assert(btn != null);
    }
```

Also, you have to make one more change in the control template in Generic.Xaml like below.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ScrollLeft">&lt;</Button>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
```

**Note:** I removed the Click event handler.

Comment: Please be aware that designers now need to add a Button control named ScrollLeft to any customized template. The Debug.Assert is nice for debug versions of the class but will not solve this issue when releasing this code. So a check `if(btn != null) { ... }` might be in order.

Comment: @Emo, Yes, you are correct.  In the production code, a check is needed. If designer missed the control then it would probably end up in NullReference exception.

Answer (score 1):

Although is it possible I recommend using Commands so the designer who replaces the template is free to pick other controls and events to bind the logic to.

Comment: Do you mean changing "Click="scrollLeft" to Command="scrollLeft"? Because both of those still return the same error. "HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"

Comment: Ah. Now I understand your problem. You cannot assign the clicked (or any other event) like that. Override the OnApplyTemplate and search for the control and then attach the handler or command. http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-a-Silverlight-Custom-Control-The-Basics.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I see what you are saying now.